# SELECT all tables from DB and query same column name in each one of them

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables that are being imported by an external app. Their names are e.g `Table_1`, `Table_296` and so on.
In each table, there is one column named `Name`.

My question is: How do I retrieve the names of all tables so I can put them into another query that will retrieve rows from each column `Name`?
Basically, I need to check for value and list a table (or tables) that contains it.

I can retrieve all tables names using the code below, but as far as I know, they can't all be SELECTED using a variable.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Table%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mydb'
```

I also know that the same column name cannot be selected if table names are not specified. Correct me if I'm wrong, please

Comment: So, take the result from your get-me-the-table-names query, loop over it, and build a statement that gathers the results from individual queries getting the necessary info from one of those tables via UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the table name then loop like below

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databaseName");
$listdbtables = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($con->query('SHOW TABLES FROM databaseName')),0);
foreach ($listdbtables as $key => $value) {
    $sqlqry = "select Name from ".$value;
    $nameResult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlqry);
    while($nam = $nameResult->fetch_array()) {
      echo($nam['Name']);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you just edited your code. The previous one did not work for some reason, and I also had it changed to mysqli. Thank you again sir.

Comment: indeed it does. I guess "SHOW TABLES" query works better in this case.

Comment: @Kumitsu Yes! Once you are selected database, there is no need for ` FROM databaseName` but if you are not selected database then its needed. Okay Finish this question by mark it as answer

Comment: Is it possible to find out which table a certain value came from?

Comment: `$arrya[$value]= $nam['Name'];` you can save in array as table name key and column value as array value so that you can refer for future, Else you have to do lot check [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1596770.aspx?How+to+get+a+Table+name+from+the+column+Value+in+Sql+Server+) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479193/find-column-name-or-table-name-of-a-specific-value)

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do with it