# Find table and column name containing one value

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have limited knowledge of SQL and have access to a SQL Server database in Python3, with no documentation and without user-friendly table and column name descriptions. I'm struggling to find where to look at for the right tables and columns.

I've written a few helper functions using Pandas to get names and tables in the database and to find table or column names containing specific strings:

```
def find_tables(tablas, s):
        return tablas.loc[(tablas.table_name.str.contains(s, case=False))].drop_duplicates('table_name')


def find_column(tablas, s):
    if isinstance(s, list):
        cond = tablas.column_name.str.contains('|'.join(s))
    else:
        cond = tablas.column_name.str.contains(s, case=False)
        
    return tablas.loc[(cond)]


def explora_tabla(tablas, s):
    return tablas.loc[(tablas.table_name.str.contains(s, case=False))]
```

Unfortunately, given odd names, this is usually not enough to pull out the information I need. Therefore I though I could try the "brute force way" to find (by value) which table and column names contain a specific value, possibly filtering for other known fields when they are available. Obviously more subtle ways to solve the problem are also welcome.

I have found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479193/find-column-name-or-table-name-of-a-specific-value), tried it with value `8004YS1LSLR` but returns an error I guess because of data type. In any case I would need to be able to match a wider range of formats.

I would like to find a general query that I could pass to `pd.read_sql` that retuns table and column names in the database containing given value that could be an integer, float, string, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking here if I am honest. Can you try elaborate? There isn't actually a question in your question.

Comment: @Larnu I hope it is clearer now

Comment: So you want to search *every* column in *every* table in a database for a specific value? There is no "simple" solution to this, if I am honest. It would have to be dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Yes, that is why I though it would be the "brute force way". I just plan to use it as a last resort, the fact that there is no documentation is a nightmare.

Comment: Do you at least know the data type for such values?

Comment: @Larnu I know the datatypes for each table and column but I do not know to which table and column the value is goin to match... so I guess I would have to try a few

Comment: What version of SQL Server..? Can we at least assume you are on a fully supported version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)

Comment: 2019, good. , however, you're almost 3 years behind on updates, I suggest getting those installed.

Comment: @Larnu unfortunately updating it is out of my scope of work and have no possibility to do that

Comment: 2019 RTM has multiple bugs in it; I strongly recommend you do. If you can't, then get whomever can to fix it.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your advice, I will try to get it updated. However I don't know if I will be able to get it done in the short term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yuck, but is based on something I had to write a while ago for a similar problem at the office.

I use a `sql_variant` here as this means that you can use it to search for other data types, and not have a bunch of implicit conversions in the `WHERE`. Note, however, that this means it will filter to the underlying data type of the `sql_variant`; if you supply an `nvarchar` it *won't* search `varchar`, `nchar` or `char` columns for example.

As I'm using `sql_variant` there's some silliness with explicitly conversions as well, which I include the definition of here too.

#### `QuoteSqlvariant`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[QuoteSqlvariant] (@SQLVariant sql_variant) 
RETURNS nvarchar(258)
AS 
/*
Written by Thom A 2021-03-21
Original Source: https://wp.larnu.uk/sql_variant-and-dynamic-sql/
Licenced under CC BY-ND 4.0
*/
BEGIN
    RETURN QUOTENAME(CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType'))) +
           CASE WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'char',N'varchar') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'MaxLength')),N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'nchar',N'nvarchar') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'MaxLength'))/2,N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'datetime2',N'datetimeoffset',N'time') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'Scale')),N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'decimal',N'numeric',N'time') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'Precision')),N',',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'Scale')),N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'varbinary') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'TotalBytes'))-4,N')')
                ELSE N''
           END;
END
GO
```

#### Solution

```
DECLARE @SearchValue sql_variant = CONVERT(varchar(15),'8004YS1LSLR'); --Explicit Converting is **IMPORTANT** here

DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @OrDelim nvarchar(10) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + N'   OR ',
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

WITH ORs AS(
    SELECT s.name AS SchemaName,
           t.name AS TableName,
           STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = CONVERT(' + fn.QuoteSqlvariant(@SearchValue) + N',@SearchValue)', @OrDelim) AS ORClauses
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
         JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
         JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
    WHERE ct.[name] = CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SearchValue,'BaseType'))
    GROUP BY s.name,
             t.name)
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName,'''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       N' + QUOTENAME(TableName,'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       *' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + @CRLF +
                         N'WHERE ' + OrClauses + N';',@CRLF)
FROM ORs;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SearchValue sql_variant', @SearchValue;
```

Comment: many thanks, the code looks good. Unfortunately I can't test it because of a lack of permissions. I was thinking of trying one call for each data type just to avoid creating a function. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score -1):

To get the column use this code:

```sql
SELECT name,is_nullable,max_length
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourtablename')
```

Comment: thanks, I'm suppose to get the column name where a row matches a given value. I'm not sure how to pass the value I'd like to match to this query.